# How can I fix "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" error in building real time chat application using Flask and React?

Tags: reactjs, flask, socket.io

I am building real time chat application using Flask and React, but I am stuck on this error.
GET http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=OqJUpKS net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

This is flask code.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config\['SECRET_KEY'\] = 'mysecret'
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="\*")

@socketio.on("message")
def handleMessage(msg):
print(msg)
send(msg, broadcast=True)

@socketio.on('connect')
def connect():
print('listening to connect')

if __name__ == '__main__':
socketio.run(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=5000, debug=True)
```

This is React code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000', {transports: \["websocket"\]} );

const App = () =\> {
const \[messages, setMessages\] = useState(\["Hello And Welcome"\]);
const \[message, setMessage\] = useState("");

useEffect(() =\> {
socket.on("message", msg =\> {
setMessages(\[...messages, msg\]);
});
return () =\> {
socket.off("message");
};
}, \[messages\]);

const onChange = e =\> {
setMessage(e.target.value);
};

const onClick = () =\> {
if (message !== "") {
socket.emit("message", message);
setMessage("");
} else {
alert("Please Add A Message");
}
};

return (
\<div\>
{messages.length \> 0 &&
messages.map((msg, index) =\> (
\<div key={index}\>
\<p\>{msg}\</p\>
\</div\>
))}
\<input value={message} name="message" onChange={onChange} /\>
\<button onClick={onClick}\>Send Message\</button\>
\</div\>
);
};

export default App;
```

I saw many similar questions and answers but they didn't work for me. Anyone who have experience help me. If you have similar code, please share with me.

I expected message communicated between server and client but nothing displayed. It seems there is error in connection.

Comment: Could you please reformat your code correctly? They are missing indentation (vital to python) and some unrelated escaping characters.